Nature-like bibliography style with hyperlinks appearing over the journal name, edition and page numbers, and year
I am writing a paper to be submitted to one of the journals of Nature's family. The default bibliography class,as far as I know, is \bibliographystyle{naturemag}. If one employs a bibliography entry which includes the url, that will appear explicitly written after the whole reference in the main text. I was wondering if there is any possibility for URL references to appear over the journal name, edition and page numbers, and year, in blue color as follows:

Any advice to achieve this goal will be of great help.

Welcome to TeX.SE. I think that what you're asking for amounts to a feature request. Feature requests are off-topic on this site. I suggest that you simply follow the submission guidelines of the journal you've chosen to submit your paper to.
